# Secure a java web service created using netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I am new to java web services. I have created a new web service using netbeans IDE and deployed it on tomcat server. Now I want to secure the webservice such that I provide username and password to access it.

Can someone guide me to a step by step tutorial of doing this. The literature available uses glassfish server.

Comment: You can start with basic authentication as explained here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html

Comment: You can secure your webservice with SSL.